# SQLAlchemy - create an instance in another instances __init__

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Newish to SQLAlchemy (so my terminology may be a bit off). I want to create a database object inside the constructor of another, but the problem is I can't add said object to the session, so I get an error.

My schema looks a bit like the following:

```
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('tag_id_seq'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    type = Column(String(1), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, type, name):
        self.type=type
        self.name=name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Tag('%s')>" % (self.id)


class Venue:
    __tablename__ = 'venue'

    tag_id = Column(Integer)
    tag_type = Column(String(1), nullable=False)
    location = Column(String(255), nullable=False)

    tag = ForeignKeyConstraint(
            (tag_id, tag_type),
            (Tag.id, Tag.type),
            onupdate='RESTRICT',
            ondelete='RESTRICT',
            )

    def __init__(self,name,location):
        self.tag = Tag('V',name)
        self.location = location
```

When I do the following:

```
session.add(Venue("Santa's Cafe","South Pole"))
```

I get an error:

```
UnmappedInstanceError: Class '__builtin__.instance' is not mapped
```

I assume this is because the the Tag object created in Venue's constructor is not added to the session. My question is how/when do I do this. (I'd really prefer to create that Tag object in the constructor if possible). I think I could do this with a scoped_session but that seems like a really bad solution.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't Venue inherit from Base?

Comment: Yes. (amongst other problems!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Inherit `Venue` from `Base`. Otherwise `Venue` won't be mapped.
2. Move `ForeignKeyConstraint` to [`__table_args__`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/declarative.html#table-configuration).
3. Replace currently meaningless `tag` property with `relationship` to `Tag`. The default value of `cascade` parameter to `relationship` contains `'save-update'` rule that will add new  referred object to the same session as parent.

From [documentation:](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship)

> `save-update` - cascade the `Session.add()` operation. This cascade
>   applies both to future and past calls to `add()`, meaning new items
>   added to a collection or scalar relationship get placed into the same
>   session as that of the parent, and also applies to items which have
>   been removed from this relationship but are still part of unflushed
>   history.

Comment: Thanks, good explanation there. Stll getting used to the way sqlalchemy tells me what is wrong.